# Flex-wrap переносит с большим расстоянием между строками

Tags: html, css

Использую flex-wrap для переноса на следующую строку, но переносит с большим расстоянием между строками. Никак не могу понять от чего это, кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным прежде?

Свойства контейнера:

```
.rec-animes{
width: 77%;
height: 619px;
position: relative;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Свойства элементов которые переносятся:

```
.rec-anime-box{
display:flex;
margin-right:24px;
width: 329px;
height: 143px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скинь сюда html код

Comment: align-content: flex-start родительскому блоку

Comment: Большое спасибо! даже не знал о таком свойстве